# Non-relativistic limit of time-dependent Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fermions, dirac-equation, spinors

Can someone point me to the derivation of the non-relativistic limit of the time-dependent Dirac equation? I'm presuming that the limit is nothing but the time-dependent Schrodinger equation.

I flipped a few books but couldn't find it.

Update: Also, is there a closed form relationship between the non-relativistic and relativistic wave functions?

Comment: It's actually the Pauli equation.

Comment: Sure. A reference to a systematic derivation will help.

Comment: The derivation of the Schrödinger equation from the Klein-Gordon equation is simpler. That is where you should start.

Comment: It's just that I need a reference for Dirac=>Schrodinger path, if available in some text.

Comment: You can find a derivation in Chapter 8 of Sakurai-Napolitano, Modern Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: Thanks, I scrolled through ch. 8 of the book but it's not there.

8 ■ Relativistic Quantum Mechanics 
8.1 Paths to Relativistic Quantum Mechanics 486 
8.2 The Dirac Equation 494 8.3 Symmetries of the Dirac Equation 501 
8.4 Solving with a Central Potential 506 
8.5 Relativistic Quantum Field Theory 514

Answer (score 1):

The Dirac equation with potentials reads
$$\left( i\hbar \partial_{ct} - e \Phi(t,x) \right) \ \left( \begin{array}{c} u(t,x)\\ v(t,x)\end{array}\right)=
 \left( \begin{array}{cc} mc  & \vec \sigma \cdot \left( - i \nabla - e A(t,x) \right) \\ \vec \sigma \cdot \left( - i \nabla - e A(t,x) \right) & - mc\end{array}\right)   \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c} u(t,x)\\ v(t,x)\end{array}\right)$$

The right hand  side operator squared  yields
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} mc & \vec \sigma \cdot \left( - i \hbar \nabla - e A(t,x) \right) \\ \vec \sigma \cdot \left( - i \nabla - e A(t,x) \right) & - mc\end{array}\right)^2$$  $$= \left( mc^2  +\left( - i\hbar  \nabla - e A(t,x) \right)^2 + i \vec \sigma \cdot \ \left( - i \hbar \nabla - e A(t,x) \right)^{2\times}\right)\quad  \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1   &0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$$

with $a^{\times 2}$ meaning the cross product with itself:
$$ i \vec \sigma \cdot \left( - i \hbar \nabla - e A(t,x) \right)^{2\times} = e \vec \sigma \cdot (\nabla \times \vec A + \vec A\times \nabla) = e \vec \sigma \cdot \vec B $$

So both components are solutions of the Klein-Gordon equation with an additional spin energy in the magnetic field $\vec B$.

$$ \left( i \hbar \partial_{ct} - e \Phi \right)^2 \ u   =  (\vec p-e \vec A)^2 \ u +  \vec \sigma \cdot \vec B \ u  + (mc)^2 \ u$$

The non relativistic approximation takes the square root of both sides and assumes the kinetic momentum  part being small with respect to the rest momentum $mc$

$$ \left( i \hbar \partial_{ct} - e \Phi \right) \ u  = 
mc \ \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{(mc)^2} \ \left(\left(  \vec p-e \vec A\right)^2 +  \vec \sigma \cdot \vec B\right) } u = mc +\frac{\left(  \vec p-e \vec A\right)^2}{2 mc} + \frac{e B}{2 mc} \vec \sigma \cdot \vec B $$